# JS lazy loading images - apply a test function to not one but many HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a small JS script for lazy image loading. I found some code here on stackoverflow and adapted for my needs but I can't figure out how to make it work on multiple elements at once.

The problem is that I need it to work on a page with multiple images and I don't want to specify an event handler for each one of them by hand as it's kinda pointles...

Is there a way to somehow bind an event that would check if an element is in the viewport and create an image inside it, keeping the `data-image` attribute as a `src` tag of the image itself? As I said, this method works on one or two images but not like 200...

```js
var isInViewport = function (elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var index = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) - bounding.top;
 if (index > 0) {
  return true;
 }
};

var image = document.querySelector('[data-image]');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
 if (isInViewport(image) == true) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
   image.innerHTML = '<img src="' + image.getAttribute('data-image') + '">';
  }, 500);
 }
}, false);
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="height: 700px; width: 100px; background-color: gold;"></div>
  <div data-image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556704503-4e4c76896741?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"></div>
  <!-- Some image directory/adress in a data attribute -->
  <div style="height: 700px; width: 100px; background-color: gold;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "scroll" and "resize" events it's possible to imitate lazy loading.

```js
let lazyImages = [...document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-image')]
let inAdvance = 300

function lazyLoad() {
    lazyImages.forEach(image => {
        if (image.offsetTop < window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset + inAdvance) {
            image.src = image.dataset.src
            image.onload = () => image.classList.add('loaded')
        }
    })
}

lazyLoad()

window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(lazyLoad, 16))
window.addEventListener('resize', _.throttle(lazyLoad, 16))
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.inspiration {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #969696;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
}
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.gallery .image {
  grid-area: span 1/span 1;
}
.gallery .image--horizontal {
  grid-area: span 1/span 2;
}
.gallery .image--vertical {
  grid-area: span 2/span 1;
}
.gallery .image--big {
  grid-area: span 2/span 2;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .gallery .image--horizontal,
  .gallery .image--vertical,
  .gallery .image--big {
    grid-area: span 1/span 1;
  }
}
.gallery img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.gallery img.lazy-image {
  opacity: 0.1;
  will-change: opacity;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.gallery img.lazy-image.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

<h1>Works in every browser</h1>
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/694" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/624" /></div>
    <div class="image image--big"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/619" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/634" /></div>
    <div class="image image--big"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/636" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/630" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/685" /></div>
    <div class="image image--horizontal"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/639" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/671" /></div>
    <div class="image image--horizontal"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/627" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/660" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/661" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/644" /></div>
    <div class="image image--horizontal"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/654" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/656" /></div>
    <div class="image image--big"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/618" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/684" /></div>
    <div class="image image--vertical"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/699" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/603" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/601" /></div>
    <div class="image image--vertical"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/646" /></div>
    <div class="image image--big"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/632" /></div>
    <div class="image image--big"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/699" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/654" /></div>
    <div class="image image--vertical"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/651" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/617" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/613" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/663" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/699" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/684" /></div>
    <div class="image image--big"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/657" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/643" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/653" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/638" /></div>
    <div class="image image--horizontal"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/669" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/676" /></div>
    <div class="image image--big"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/618" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/601" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/608" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img class="lazy-image" data-src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/624" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is quite laggy in older browsers from what i see... (I even have a special PC with 256MB of DDR1ram + pentium CPU to test how slow things work) Don't you know any good methods of how to prevent it?